# VB Macro to create new workbooks and prefill the new workbooks from the master sheet

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet

I have a macro which works as follows:

I have a workbook which has four tabs in it, 
*Index - Contains a list of Building Information ( 5 Columns in total starting from A finishing E, some months there can be 3 rows and other months there could be 100 rows
*Template - a template page with basic building info
*Data - A checklist
*B2 - Another checklist

what I need the macro to do is to create a new workbook which contains worksheets "Template" "Data" and "B2"

The new workbooks need to be named in accordance with the building name contained in column A on the index worksheet

I then need the list located on the index tab to copy to cells F2, F3, F4, F5, F6 F5 on the template tab for each new workbook ( one for each header )

Below is the code which works but currently only prefills to cell F2 on the template worksheet in the new workbook

```
    Sub temp()
Dim wb As Workbook, sh1 As Worksheet, lr As Long, rng As Range
Set sh1 = Sheets("Index") 'Edit sheet name
Set sh2 = Sheets("B2") 'Edit sheet name
Set sh3 = Sheets("Data") 'Edit sheet name
lr = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = sh1.Range("A2:A" & lr)
    For Each c In rng
        Sheets("Template").Copy 'Edit sheet name
        Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
        wb.Sheets(1).Range("F2") = c.Value
        sh2.Copy After:=wb.Sheets(1)
        sh3.Copy After:=wb.Sheets(2)
        wb.SaveAs c.Value & ".xlsx"
        wb.Close False
    Next
End Sub
```

Thanks heaps... im sure I have got 90% of this done just the finishing touches

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Sub temp()
Dim wb As Workbook, sh1 As Worksheet, lr As Long, rng As Range, x as long
Set sh1 = Sheets("Index") 'Edit sheet name
Set sh2 = Sheets("B2") 'Edit sheet name
Set sh3 = Sheets("Data") 'Edit sheet name
lr = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = sh1.Range("A2:A" & lr)
x = 2
For Each c In rng
    Sheets("Template").Copy 'Edit sheet name
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    wb.Sheets(1).Range("F" & x) = c.Value
    x = x + 1
    sh2.Copy After:=wb.Sheets(1)
    sh3.Copy After:=wb.Sheets(2)
    wb.SaveAs c.Value & ".xlsx"
    wb.Close False
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Ashton, Thanks heaps for your response, your code completes all the tasks but it does not prefill the new "Template" tab with the information collected on the "Index" tab in the original spread sheet. i.e call A2 on the "Index" tab should populate into cell F2 on the "Template tab of the first workbook created, and then B2 into F3 and B3 into F4 and then B4 into F5. once this is correct it needs to move to the next line and complete for A3 to F2 in the same pattern. Thanks heaps for helping me out.